# how to update an app from google play that installed from other market?

Tags: android, google-play

I have an Android app released in some markets as well as **google play**.

But when I install the app from another market, I can't update it via Google Play because it says **app not installed** but when I update the app from the market that I installed it then Success Updates!

And sometimes the update button is not displayed by default in Google Play

**so why ?**

Comment: you likely use different signatures on those 2 apps. You can update only the app that is signed with same signature as the update for it.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko the signatures of both app is same !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found my answer !
google play has an option that add another sign to my personal sign , so if i want to my app has same sign in all markets should disable this option.

note that you should disable this option at first app upload and if you active it and want to disable it after published , unfortunately you can't !